# Convert nested foreach to Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert this code snippet to one `Linq`?
(I'd like to remove foreach)

```
var resultList = new List<Item>();

var query = dataList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Pruefdatum, x.Plakettenjahr });
foreach (var q in query)
{
   Item temp = new Item();
   foreach (Item item in q)
   {
      switch (item.Plakart)
      {
         case "HU":
            temp.HU = item.Anzahl;
            break;
         case "SP":
            temp.SP = item.Anzahl;
            break;
      }
   }
   temp.Pruefdatum = q.Last().Pruefdatum;
   temp.Plakettenjahr = q.Last().Plakettenjahr;
   resultList.Add(temp);
}

var result = resultList;
```

**Data:**

```
public static List<Item> dataList = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-13 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =6 }, //0
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-13 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "SP", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =1 }, //1
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =1 }, //2
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "SP", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =2 }, //3
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-18 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =3 }, //4
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-18 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "SP", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =1 }, //5
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-20 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =6 }, //6
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-21 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =2 }, //7
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-22 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =8 }, //8
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-25 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "20", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =2 }, //9
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-25 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "20", Plakart = "SP", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =7 }, //10
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-25 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =9 }, //11
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-28 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "20", Plakart = "SP", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =1 }, //12
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-28 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 0, SP = 0, Anzahl =5 }, //13
};
```

**Result:**

```
public static List<Item> result = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-13 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 6, SP = 1}, //0
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 1, SP = 2}, //1
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-18 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 3, SP = 1}, //2
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-20 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 6, SP = 0}, //3
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-21 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 2, SP = 0}, //4
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-22 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 8, SP = 0}, //5
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-25 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "20", Plakart = "HU", HU = 2, SP = 7}, //6
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-25 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 9, SP = 0}, //7
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-28 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "20", Plakart = "SP", HU = 0, SP = 1}, //8
    new Item{Pruefdatum = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-28 00:00:00"), Plakettenjahr = "21", Plakart = "HU", HU = 5, SP = 0} //9
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove foreach? Your code seems pretty straightforward to me, I doubt you can get it any cleaner - in particular not using LINQ, which is for **queyring**, not **updating** items in a collection.

Comment: I want to know that, how can I do it without foreach. Is it possible or not?

Comment: First things first, cache `q.Last()`.

Comment: You can´t do it without foreach, you **have** to iterate the items **returned** from the query and update them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
    dataList
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Pruefdatum, x.Plakettenjahr })
        .Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Pruefdatum = x.Key.Pruefdatum,
            Plakettenjahr = x.Key.Plakettenjahr,
            HU = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Plakart == "HU")?.Anzahl ?? 0,
            SP = x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Plakart == "SP")?.Anzahl ?? 0,
        });
```

EDIT: I missed the `Plakart` field, but it is also not really clear on what determines its value from the original example (`temp` never gets `Plakart` assigned). In that view, my listing above yields exactly the same results as the original code listing does, although that mismatches the list that is claimed to be the result.

Also, I'm using `Key` instead of `Last()` because there is no need to use the last item in a query result if you are already grouping by it. Which means that there will be no variation between first or last or any, really. If the sort order *is* important, you can always swap `Key` back out for `Last()`.

Now, based on the result data set, the only rule I can defer from it that determines the value of `Plakart` is if HU > 0 then HU else SP, which would result in this being added to my select clause:

```
            Plakart = x.Any(y => y.Plakart == "HU" && y.Anzahl > 0) ? "HU" : "SP",
```